# How to split outbound traffic by destination IPs on aws with static IP?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, iptables, vpn, nat

**Conditions are below.**

- Use static IP for all outbound traffic.
- Send traffic through VPN Connection if it has the specific destination IPs.
- Send traffic through the Internet if it has NOT the specific destination IPs.

**And current setup.**

To use static IP for outbound traffic, I setup EC2 instance as a NAT with below configuration,

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.32.0/19 -j MASQUERADE
```

and configured Route Table to send all subnet traffic(0.0.0.0/0) to that EC2 instance's network interface.

But I have to use VPN if it has specific destination IP. How do I configure the network on AWS?

Comment: Do you really need a NAT instance? Can you just use an Elastic IP address? That won't scale past one instance, so a NAT instance is a better solution for scale. You can start with an elastic IP attached to one server and move it to a NAT server later.

Comment: Regarding the VPN, assume you have a VPG in your VPC? Just add a route table entry for the IPs that need to go down the VPN to the route table associated with your subnet(s).

Answer (score 3):

You just have to add a route:

```
route add -net 192.168.100.0/24 gw 192.168.100.1 metric 1
```

In this example 192.168.100.0/24 is the VPN network and 192.168.100.1 is your VPN gateway.

More info about routing on AWS can be found here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html